# $.post not posting data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my code below for page.php file.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/new-landing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ans1 = "home";
    function aa(){
        $.post("ajax.php", { "ans": "test" }, function(data){
            alert("Posted");
        }, "html");
    };
</script>
<a href="#" id="q1" onClick="javascript:aa();" >click</a>
```

and this is where i want to see if my data is posted.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $te = $_POST['ans'];
    $_SESSION['demo'] = $te;
    echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,'/n')."</pre>";
?>
```

when i click the anchor tag. the alert box is shown. but when i refresh the ajax.php page. it shows an error..Notice: Undefined index: ans in ajax.php on line 3

and the print of session is also empty.

```
Array(
   [demo] => 
)
```

Comment: Hi Harsh - did we resolve your problem? If not, please update your question and/or post a comment under an answer so that we will be alerted that you need more assistance. If this question has been answered, though, please close the question by choosing a "best answer".

Answer (score 0):

> but when i refresh the ajax.php page. it shows an error

It sounds like you want to **set** the session variable when a value is **posted**, and **get** the session variable otherwise:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['ans'])) {
    $te = $_POST['ans'];
    $_SESSION['demo'] = $te;
}
echo "<pre>".print_r($_SESSION,'/n')."</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: its just for the test purpose. need to just find out why is it not getting data stored in session in ajax.php

Comment: but still where is the data been posted ?

Comment: When you visit `ajax.php` directly, there is no `$_POST` variable. You need to test if the posted variable exists or not, which I provided in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` and `$.get` are just shorthand versions of the more structured `$.ajax()`, so I prefer using the latter. The additional structure keeps me straight.

Since you are using jQuery anyway, I would re-structure your code like this:

```
$('#q1').click(function() {
    var test = "Hello there";
    $.ajax(function() {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: 'ans=' +test+ '&anothervarname=' + anothervarvalue,
        success: function(recd_data) {
            alert('Rec'd from PHP: ' + recd_data );
        }
    });
});
```

Note that the `data:` line is for example purposes and does not match with your code -- just showing you how to pass variables over to the PHP side.

Of course, the above includes removing the inline javascript -- never a good idea -- from your anchor tag HTML, thus:

```
 <a href="#" id="q1" >click</a>
```

---

Also, on the PHP side, you can verify that things are working by adding a test at the top.  Matching with the `data:` line in the example AJAX code, it would look like this:

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['ans'];
$b = $_POST['anothervarname'];

$response = '<h1>Received at PHP side:</h1>';
$response .= 'Variable [ans] has value: ' . $a . '<br>';
$response .= 'Variable [anothervarname] has value: ' . $b . '<br>';

echo $response;
```

Important: Note the use of `echo`, not `return`, to send values back to the AJAX script.

Also note that you **must** deal with the stuff returned from PHP **in the AJAX `success:` function ONLY**.  If you need access to that data outside of the `success:` function, then you can stick the data into a hidden `<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenInput">` element, like this:

```
success: function(recd_data) {
    $('#myHiddenInput').html(recd_data);
}
```

---

Here are some additional examples of simple AJAX constructions:

[A simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

Comment: Although this is a nice answer, it doesn't answer the question at hand whatsoever!

Comment: Actually, it does.  If the OP places a test at the top of the PHP file (`ajax.php`) and echos back any variables he has POSTed (or even just `die('Here I am');` then he will see exactly what is going on.  Restructuring his ajax code will also simplify the situation and help with solving the problem.