# jQuery/PHP Post Failure

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, t-sql

I've got slightly convoluted jQuery and PHP problem here.  On my index.php, a call to a javascript function `getCalls()` is made.

```
function getCalls()
{
    $('#transportDiv').load('getCalls.php');
}
```

getCalls.php does a select from SQL database.  It returns a table with the requested data, plus a dynamically generated form for each row, plus a dynamically generated jQuery post function for each dynamically generated form (these are being echo()'d, by the way):

```
 <tr>
   //Static table data here
 </tr>
<form id='form$id' action='update.php' method='post'> 
  <tr id='tr$id' style='{display: none;}'>
    <td class='$tdClass'>
      <input type='text' id='txt_municipality' name='municipality' value='$municipality'>
    </td>
    //a lot more inputs omitted
  </tr>
</form> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#submitButton'.$id.'").click( 
    function() 
    {
     $.post( $("#form'.$id.'").attr("action"), 
             $("#form'.$id.':input").serializeArray(), 
             function(info)
             {
              $("#responseDiv").html(info); 
             }
           );
     getCalls();
    }
  );
  </script>
```

`$id` is a PHP variable containing the unique identifier for each row in SQL (BTW, those `'.$id.'` lines are correct, they are within an echo with single quotes).  All of this shows up as expected in my `#transportDiv` after `getCalls()` is invoked, so no problem there.  When `#submitButton` is clicked, it calls update.php, but there is no post data in the $_POST array:

```
 echo $_POST['municipality'];
```

That's all I have it doing right now.  `#responseDiv` is populated by the jQuery post with "Notice: Undefined index: municipality in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\comm\update.php on line 3".  A `var_dump()` on $_POST prints "array(0)"

I've been stuck on this for days.. any thoughts?

**UPDATE**

gibberish suggested this change to the dynamic jQuery calls:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $("#submitButton'.$id.'").click(function(){
    var url = $("#form'.$id.'").attr("action");
   alert("Is this url correct: " + url);
  $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url : url,
     data : "somevarname=Hello there",
     success: function(info) {
         $("#responseDiv").html(info); 
     }
  });
 });
</script>
```

This does successfully send the `somevarname` variable through.  So I guess the question now is: how can I serialize the whole form and send it through?  I guess that's a question for another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load()` method does not do what you think it does.

Your question states `getCalls.php does a select from SQL database` -- but this won't happen if you use the jQuery `.load()` method, it will only work if you use AJAX. This is because the server must run the PHP, while `.load()` runs at the browser. The only way for the browser to request that PHP be executed (and data returned) is via AJAX.

I suspect what you really want to do is to use AJAX, like this:

```
function getCalls(){

    $.ajax(function() {
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getCalls.php',
        success: function(recd_data) {
            $('#transportDiv').html( recd_data );
        }
    });

}
```

Please see the links at bottom of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724011/post-not-posting-data/18724684#18724684) for more AJAX examples.

---

**Update:**

Restructured AJAX code for test discussed in comments:

```
$("#submitButton'.$id.'").click(function(){
    var url = $("#form'.$id.'").attr("action");
    alert('Is this url correct: ' + url);
    $.ajax({
        type = "POST",
        url = url,
        data = 'somevarname=Hello there',
        success: function(info) {
            $("#responseDiv").html(info); 
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: So.. it's a scope issue?  The getCalls function _appears_ to be doing what I want it to, which is populating my transportDiv with the relevant editable forms.  But does using `load()` not work for loading javascript?

Comment: Huh, getCalls.php does indeed do a select.  Should I be confused over the fact that it works as is?  My problem is using the save buttons that were already successfully generated by getCalls.php

Comment: But the PHP _does_ work.  The query is executed and the results are placed my div.

Comment: Ah. There you go -- it was me who didn't understand. I didn't realize your approach would work, but it does! My turn to learn. On your other ajax call (`$.post()`), how about just echoing back the entire post array: `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';` and see what you get in your #responseDiv?

Comment: I am also an advocate of using the `$.ajax()` structure outlined in the SO post I keep referring to, as the additional structure is helpful when troubleshooting, as now.

Comment: Thanks for your patience.. my way is probably a bit hackish.  Echoing the entire array gives me this:"Array
(
)".  The code is clearly hitting update.php, but somehow the post data isn't making it there.

Comment: That tells you that your variables (or JSON data) is not coming through. Try completely restructuring your AJAX code (should take 3 mins) just to run a test and see what is echoed out.  See update to my answer (give me 3 mins to write it)

Comment: I will read up on using the `$.ajax()` syntax and see if I can try that instead.

Comment: Made a change to my suggested test code (so that you have data echoed out into the #responseDiv). Sorry.

Comment: Hmm, after fixing some syntax errors, you code does send `somevarname` through successfully.  So my problem I guess was my attempt to serialize all my form data into an array and send that.  Allow me to update my question...

Comment: Best to close this question (select a correct answer) and ask a new question. For one thing, it adds the new question to the top of the list and gives opportunity for more people to notice it and respond.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'll do that.